# Limitations on push notifications for multiple apps from the same server

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am attempting to send push notifications for multiple apps in quick succession. Each app has its own certificate, of course, and I am using the appropriate certificate for each push token in my database.

I am finding that only the first app's 'batch' is arriving. In my php script I am cycling through each app, collecting the messages for that bundle identifier, opening the connection using the corresponding certificate, and sending the messages. Every single message is reported as successfully delivered.

If I switch the order in which I process the apps, I always find that all notifications for the first app ID all arrive fine, and the rest vanish into the ether.

Could someone shed some light on what might be happenning?

Comment: Just wondering if you found a solution for the problem yet. I have the exact same problem.