# iOS - correct way to send push notification to multiple apps from the same server at the same time with the same message and payload

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have two separate applications in "development", lets call them App A and App B , that are supposed to receive the exact same message and payload from the same server as a push notification. Both have different application ids, certificate requests, provisioning profiles, development APN certificates, and produce different tokens.

If I send a push notification to either application individually each application will receive a notification. But if I try to send a push notification to each application concurrently, only the fist application will receive the notification. But I will receive no errors for the other application.

I have tried to delay the push notification by up to 10 seconds between sending the push notification to the last application without success. Is there some way that I need to handle the connections to the apple server to enable this type of push notifications?

Also note that there is another question that is having the exact same issue, but without any answers. [Limitations on push notifications for multiple apps from the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248733/limitations-on-push-notifications-for-multiple-apps-from-the-same-server)

I was able to get the notifications to be delivered to both of the applications successfully by closing the previous connection. This is not recommended by Apple, and they state that I should keep them open, as there is a potential to have a lot of notifications pushed per day to each application.

> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack

[Read More Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)

Comment: have you found any solution?
I have written the code but have another problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210258/correct-way-of-sending-ios-bulk-push-notifications-in-php?noredirect=1#comment58136089_35210258

Answer (score 0):

try to use two instance of your server , and keep your connection open while sending.

Connect each instance to a different port: 2195, 2196

Comment: Can you provide an example in php? Also I thought that port 2196 was for feedback only.

Comment: Could you up vote my question please so we can get an example from someone.

Comment: post your php code, so we can modify it, and test it.