# Correct way of sending IOS Bulk push notifications in PHP

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notification on IOS using PHP there are 300,000 device tokens

I have written a small routine, on each execution the routine send notification to 100 devices, and after 1 second delay routine is executed again  and notification is sent to next 100 devices, routine is as follows

```
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => 'Energy is full',
        'sound' => 'default',
        'badge' => '0'
);


$url = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ProductionCertificate.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'my pass phrase');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'trusted_ca.cer');

$fp = stream_socket_client($url, $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp) { return -1;}
    foreach($OneHundredTokens as $deviceToken) {
        $payload = json_encode($body, 256);
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    }

fclose($fp);
```

Some time this routine works perfectly fine, and i have seen sent notifications on devices.

However some times it gives following error

> Warning: fwrite(): SSL: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine.

**My Questions are:**

1. Is it a correct way to send bulk notification?
2. I open a connection once and write data(notification) for 100 devices, and then close the connection, or is it better to open connection for each device token and then close?
3. What is causing above error?

**Findings**
Sent approx `90,000` push notifications (100 in single connection open and next 100 after 1 second delay)
Approx `60,000` failed (`fwrite` failed) with above error and approx `30,000` push were successfully sent (fwrite returned positive integers indicating number of bytes written).

Comment: `if (!$fp) { return -1;}` -> `if (!$fp) { echo $errstr .'(' . $errno . ')';}` change that line and get back to us

Comment: I am actually using following line if not $fp
`exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);` but it never was true (mean always valid $fp)